# AppCompat, colorAccent, colorPrimary and colorPrimaryDark is not working on AIDE

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools, android-appcompat, aide-ide

I'm currently using AIDE for App developing and still learning and practicing but unfortunately every time I input colorPrimary, colorPrimaryDark and colorAccent with AppCompat, squiggy lines appears. I'm on Marshmallow but still it doesn't support it. I even used SDK Manager from Playstore and I downloaded the repository and the support library and still no effects. What should I do? Is there anything I need to fix?

Comment: can you show your styles and additionally your build.gradle?

Comment: I cant post pictures yet. How?

Answer (score 1):

You can only use colorPrimary, colorPrimaryDark and colorAccent in the values-v21 folder... :)

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar">
<item name="android:colorPrimary">#ff607d8b</item>
<item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">#ff263238</item>
</style>
</resources>

Comment: THERE IT IS! WOOO! Thanks! It worked. I just missed to put '@android:' . You saved my butt! Thanks!!!!

Comment: Thank you! Was messing around for hours in values-folder